# What does "I want him to know I want him to know" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

Lately, I watched Kill Bill (Vol. 1), with quite an attention. At the last (when Beatrix speaks to Sophie), I got confused by a few dialogues. She said,

> "I want him to know what I know. I want him to know I want him to know"

The first sentence isn't a problem. But, the second sentence looks as if she's repeating *"I want him to know"*. What does the phrase really mean? Is it simply repetition, or is she meaning something else? And, is it the right way to phrase it?

Comment: *"I want him to know what I know."* = [What I know] is what I want him to know. *"I want him to know I want him to know"* = [I want him to know (whatever I want him to know)] is what I want him to know. So, in short, besides that I want that him to know what that I know, that I also want that him to know that that I want that him to know that purposely, intentionally, and explicitly.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: Wow! That's really *convincing*. Um, It'd be nice if you post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't remember that line (and probably most parts of the movie :-), but it still sounds cool anyway.

> *"I want him to know what I know. I want him to know I want him to know."*

Basically, she is saying that she wants him to know [what she knows], and she doesn't want just that, she wants him to know that [she wants him to know], too.
<sub>(I use brackets as reading aid, to make it easier to group words together when reading.)</sub>

Let's recap:

> ***"I want him to know what I know."*** = [What I know] is what I want him to know.
>   ***"I want him to know I want him to know"*** = [That I want him to know (whatever I want him to know)] is what I want him to know. The original might be easier to read if we add a *that* to make the clause more obvious, like this: *"I want him to know [(that) I want him to know]."* Grammatically, this *that* can be (and often is) omitted.

So, in short, besides she wants him to know what she knows, she also wants him to know that she wants him to know that, purposely, intentionally, and explicitly.

Comment: Alright, I'm totally convinced now. Thanks Damkerng ;-)

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for accepting my answer. However, it's recommended to wait for a while (maybe at least several hours) to encourage other users to post their answers (which might be even better than the first one), even when you believe that the first one is correct. (For example, those who can still remember the movie might be able to provide more depth to that line in the context of the movie, while I simply read it straightforwardly.)

Comment: Oh, yeah! I understand. Okay, I'll rewind the clock back to the second before I accepted your answer :P

Comment: Dear Damkerng, I think you left another question. Is that way of "repetitive" (confusing) framing right? (I mean, grammatically?) o_O

Comment: That sentence is grammatical. However, not every clause will be grammatical when being repeated twice, consecutively. (For example, \*"He loves her he loves her". -- \* denotes ungrammatical usage.) That sentence from the movie is grammatical because the latter part is a subordinate clause (with *that* being omitted). -- We say something like this all the time. My favorite one is perhaps, *"I don't know what you did or didn't do, but I do know that I can't know what you do or you don't know. You know?"* (from *Veep*).

Comment: *Fascinating* (especially the last part) ;-)

Answer (score 11):

The second sentence has an implicit *that* in it:

> I want him to know [that] I want him to know.

This sort of *that* is optional in English. You can leave them out so long as doing so isn't confusing.

Comment: True, but I think this is a case where the removal makes the statement less clear. In writing, I wouldn't do it. In speech, you can get away with it by using proper emphasis (i.e. "I want him to *know* I want him to know.") And that's why it works in the film.

Comment: @trlkly, I think it would have benefited from an explicit _that_ here. This is the scene (go to about 2:15): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IY_aqr_tQo

Comment: Yep... That *intentionally* leaving "that" is exactly the cause for my confusion. Thanks for your answer :)